# Get number of days from month number

Tags: javascript, arrays, input

The biggest JS noob in UK trying to get the days in a month when you write 1-12 in a input.

Are there any awesome person who can tell me what I'm doing wrong?

**JS :**

```
window.onload = funkytown;

var mnd = [[0, "Jan"], [1, "Feb"], [2, "Mar"], [3, "Apr"], [4, "Mai"], [5, "Jun"], [6, "Jul"], [7, "Aug"], [8, "Sep"], [9, "Okt"], [10, "Nov"], [11, "Des"]];

var days = [[0, 31], [1, 28], [2, 31], [3, 30], [4, 31], [5, 30], [6, 31], [7, 31], [8, 30], [9, 31], [10, 30], [11, 31]];

function funkytown() {  
    document.getElementById("button").onclick = calender;
}
function calender() {
    var tall = parseint(document.getElementById)("box").value;
    if(tall >= 1 && tall <= 12) {
        var mndminus = tall - 1;

        for(i = 0; i < mnd.length; i++) {
            if(mnd[i][0] == mndminus) {
                document.getElementById("text").innerHTML = mnd[i][1] + " - " + days[i][1];
            }
        }
    }
}
```

**HTML :**

```
<input type="number" id="box" max="12" />
<input type="button" id="button" value="Trykk" />
<span id="text"></span>
```

Thanks!

Comment: don't hard-code the month length, it's wrong next year for example. use the Date() object methods to calculate the number of days in a given month instead of relying on a dictionary.

Comment: Because of leap year right? Yeah, I didn't have to take that in consideration this time but thanks for your input dude! Appreciate it :D

Comment: You already know what is going wrong. After all, you saw it happen before your eyes and decided to ask on Stack Overflow. So why not describe in your post what, exactly, goes wrong? See [How do I ask a good question?](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask). (Also, as a new user, you may want to read the [introductory Tour](http://stackoverflow.com/tour).)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have just to replace this line :

```
var tall = parseint(document.getElementById)("box").value;
```

By :

```
var tall = parseInt(document.getElementById("box").value);
```

You have `parseint` that should be `parseInt` and `)` after `getElementById` that should be in the end of line.

Hope this helps.

---

```js
var mnd = [[0, "Jan"], [1, "Feb"], [2, "Mar"], [3, "Apr"], [4, "Mai"], [5, "Jun"], [6, "Jul"], [7, "Aug"], [8, "Sep"], [9, "Okt"], [10, "Nov"], [11, "Des"]];

var days = [[0, 31], [1, 28], [2, 31], [3, 30], [4, 31], [5, 30], [6, 31], [7, 31], [8, 30], [9, 31], [10, 30], [11, 31]];

function funkytown() {  
    document.getElementById("button").onclick = calender;
}
function calender() {
    var tall = parseInt(document.getElementById("box").value);
    if(tall >= 1 && tall <= 12) {
        var mndminus = tall - 1;

        for(i = 0; i < mnd.length; i++) {
            if(mnd[i][0] == mndminus) {
                document.getElementById("text").innerHTML = mnd[i][1] + " - " + days[i][1];
            }
        }
    }
}

funkytown();
```

```html
<input type="number" id="box" max="12" />
<input type="button" id="button" value="Trykk" />
<span id="text"></span>
```

Answer (score 1):

As [dandavis](https://stackoverflow.com/users/2317490/dandavis)'s comment pointed
out, February does not always have 28 days due to leap years. You would be better
off creating a function to figure out how many days are in a month.  Luckily,
there is a relatively easy way to do this with JavaScript. If you set the date
to `0` using either the [Date constructor](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Date#Constructor)
or
[Date.prototype.setDate](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Date/setDate),
the resulting `Date` object will be set to the last day of the previous month,
using this we can easily create a function to get the number of days in a month.

```
function getDaysInMonth(month) {
  var d = new Date();
  d.setMonth(month + 1);
  d.setDate(0);
  return d.getDate();
}
```

This function expects `month` to be zero-based like the `Date` constructor
(meaning it expects `month` to be a number between `0` and `11` instead of `1`
and `12`).

```
  var days = getDaysInMonth(mndminus);
```

I would also recommend using a different data structure to look up the month
name. Instead of looping through an array of two-element arrays, use an object
as a dictionary.

```
var monthLookup = {
  0: "Jan",
  1: "Feb",
  2: "Mar",
  3: "Apr",
  4: "Mai",
  5: "Jun",
  6: "Jul",
  7: "Aug",
  8: "Sep",
  9: "Okt",
  10: "Nov",
  11: "Des"
};
```

Then looking up the month is as easy as `monthLookup[mndminus]`.

With these changes your code would look something like this:

```
var getDaysInMonth = function (month) {
    var d = new Date();
    d.setMonth(month + 1);
    d.setDate(0);
    return d.getDate();
  },
  monthLookup = {
    0: "Jan",
    1: "Feb",
    2: "Mar",
    3: "Apr",
    4: "Mai",
    5: "Jun",
    6: "Jul",
    7: "Aug",
    8: "Sep",
    9: "Okt",
    10: "Nov",
    11: "Des"
  },
  calender = function () {
    var tall = parseInt(document.getElementById("box").value, 10),
      mndminus;

    if (tall >= 1 && tall <= 12) {
      mndminus = tall - 1;
      document.getElementById("text").innerHTML = monthLookup[mndminus] + " - " + getDaysInMonth(mndminus);
    }
  },
  funkytown = function () {
    document.getElementById("button").onclick = calender;
  };

window.onload = funkytown;
```

You'll notice that I used function declarations instead of function statements.
[This
article](https://javascriptweblog.wordpress.com/2010/07/06/function-declarations-vs-function-expressions/)
does a good job of explaining what each of them are and why it's usually a good
practice to use declarations instead of statements.

Something to lookout for, remember to always declare your variables!
Your original code didn't declare `i`, which makes it an implicit global.
Implicit globals can cause all sorts of weird bugs, especially if it is a common
variable name like `i` that is likely to be used elsewhere in your code. Also,
if you are using a loop to search an array, you can use the [`break`
statement](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/break)
to exit the loop early once you have found the item you are looking for. Without
a `break;` statement your code tests all twelve items in the array no matter
what month you are searching for, even if it is January and found on the first
iteration.

I would also recommend learning to use [JSHint](http://jshint.com/) or [JSLint](http://jslint.com/), they are great tools to help you improve your code. They are particularly good at spotting common errors like implicit globals, and will save you lots of time debugging by pointing those things out before they drive you mad.

Comment: Or much easier way `return new Date(year, month, 0).getDate();` ... just because year... anyway +1, clean approach.

Comment: @nelek Yeah, the reason I did it the way I did was because you don't need to pass a year into the function. If you are already collecting the year, and/or want to be able to set the year manually, I agree using a `Date` constructor would be more succinct.